# How to use Xdebug on two different XAMPPs (PHP 8)

Tags: php, xampp, xdebug, php-8

I've being working with XAMPP (PHP 7.4) and using Xdebug without any problem. But recently I installed another XAMPP to have a different version of PHP (PHP 8) on the same device.

Maybe installing 2 XAMPPs is not the best solution but it works for me. The problem is that even though I've tried to install Xdebug on this new XAMPP, it doesn't work. **It doesn't show any errors**, it just doesn't stop on the breakpoints I've put.

I downloaded the correct version of the Xdebug dll from the official page and followed the same steps I followed the first time I installed it on the PHP 7.4 XAMPP. BTW, the old XAMPP still works and has no problem debugging.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to run multiple  versions of PHP/Apache/MySQL/mariaDB all seperately but on the same machine WAMPServer is a better bet. Also XDEBUG comes pre installed in WAMPServer.

Comment: I'll check WAMP, but I've read xampp is more powerful. Also, I shut down a xampp to work with the other one.